# Nativescript Vue (mobile app) - How to pass selected item data from listview in modal back to main app?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Again, I'm still new with Nativescript Vue.  I've tried hard to make it work via $navigateTo but gave up and switch over to $showModal instead....This is where I'm stuck at.  I've see FEW examples with Nativescript Vue for mobile app but it only show passing data to modal as in one way.

What I'm trying to do is to pass the selected item from this:

AirportList Screenshot below

[AirportList modal from Airportlist.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnY4y.jpg)

and put the selected item under "Airport Name: " (See screenshot below)

[Custom page in App.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arn2q.jpg)

You can see my project at https://github.com/stahlie/first-ns-app

This is where I'm struggling in the code

```
<CardView class="cardStyle" elevation="40" radius="10">
   <StackLayout class="cardContent"  > 
     <Label textWrap="true" text="Airport Name:"/>
     <TextField v-bind:text="SelectedAirportName" hint="Tap to Select" editable="false" @tap="onCustomItemTap"/>
    </StackLayout>
</CardView>
```

In script section:

```
onCustomItemTap() {
  const newId = new Date().getTime();
  this.$showModal(AirportList, { props: { id : newId }, fullscreen: true });

},
```

In AirportList.vue in section area

```
onAirportNameTap(args) {
 // const selectedairport
    alert(args.index + " " + args.item.faaID + " " +  args.item.airportName);
},
```

I'm just stuck at this and couldn't figure out how to pass args.item.faaID and args.item.airportName back to the App.vue in that TextField area... Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing changed props in $navigateBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155029/passing-changed-props-in-navigateback)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.   I used that example in the link and ended up getting 

    ReferenceError: source is not defined

I'm not sure why I got that error.  I've gone through my code and compared it to this example.

Comment: `ReferenceError` happens when you use something without declaring, so I'm pretty sure it's something with your code not the approach. If you share the Playground sample for your issue, I could take a look.

Comment: Sure.  My project is on local laptop on Linux. How do I upload it to playground? Sidekick?

Comment: Also I already have it on github...you can view it at: https://github.com/stahlie/first-ns-app     Please note that this project uses .db file via Sqlite

Comment: I don't think you can simply upload whole project to Playground, instead you will have to upload set of files / folder and adjust your `app.js` in Playground accordingly. Playground is quick way to share & debug code as we wouldn't have to set it up locally every time.

Comment: I can't get it to work on playground since it doesn't support nativescript-sqlite...nor I'm able to upload .db...   the component that it $navigateTo  load up the list from SQLite database as a ListView...the very same thing I'm trying to pass the Item info back to App.vue...I thought I declared source.  anyway I'll go back to $showModal and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Manoj   Thank you for your time.. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parent-child: you can `this.$emit("event", { key: 'value' })` in your modal function `onAirportNameTap()` and listen for it on the parent by having a `:event="processEvent"` binding on the custom element tag.

For modal: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/#returning-data-from-the-modal (seems to be the best way).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it does.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattStaley If you don't mind, selecting this as the answer would help me a bit! Glad I could help.

Comment: Done.   One more question...How do I use the "data" from below to update my <TextField>  above..

       onCustomItemTap: function(args) {
         const newId = new Date().getTime();
         this.$showModal(AirportList, { props: { id : newId }, fullscreen: true }).then(data => console.log(data);
}   

I kept running into undefined error when I replaced console.log(data) to SelectedAirport = data;

Comment: I would try to use an async function instead of .then(), it would look like:
```onCustomItemTap: async function(args) {
  const newId = new Date().getTime();
  const data = await this.$showModal(AirportList, {
    props: { id : newId },
    fullscreen: true
  })

  SelectedAirport = data;
}
```