# How do I pass data back to previous page using `navigateBack`?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using navigateTo to open a page with listview and would like to pass the results back using navigateBack but unable to achieve that. Any idea?

Comment: There is an answer to this by Manoj here, [passing params on navigateBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155029/passing-changed-props-in-navigateback)

Comment: Or, you could set properties in your viewModel which should be accessible to both pages, then in the receiving page, use the properties to update the listview followed by a listview.refresh().

Answer (score 0):

With Service class and Observable, you can achieve this.

notify.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs-compat/Subject';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotifyService {

private refreshDataForView = new Subject<any>();
refreshDataForParentViewObservable$ = this.refreshDataForView.asObservable();

public relaodDataForParentView(data: any) {
    if (data) {
    this.refreshDataForView.next(data);
    }
}
}
```

---

Second componenet.ts

```
  constructor(
    private notifyService: NotifyService
  ) {  }

  goBack() {
    this.notifyService.relaodDataForParentView({ data: 'any data you wanrt to pass here ' });
    this.router.back();
  }
```

---

First component.ts

```
reloadDataSubscription: any;

constructor(
    private notifyService: NotifyService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.reloadDataSubscription = this.notifyService.refreshDataForParentViewObservable$
 .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('======', res);
    // do what you want to do with the data passed from second view
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajdeo Das. I eventually did some what similar to this to achieve it. But I thing there should be a better way of doing this in nativescript instead of handling it by ourself.